# Display 1 SPAN A on left and 2 SPAN (B and C)on the right on top of each other

Tags: html, css, position

How can i display something like this:

[image]

JSFIDDLE HERE:

http://jsfiddle.net/Djtk9/1/

```
 div {

   border: 1px solid black;
   height: 200px;
   width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
 }

 span {
   border: 1px red solid;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Take out display:inline-block? That will get your A, B, and C on the same line as one another. And this is a vague question, what are you trying to get exactly?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Djtk9/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Djtk9/2/)

```
#a{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: red;
}

#b {
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: yellow;
}

#c {
    background: blue;
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```